# Problem in understanding how to manage templates

Tags: theming

I'm new to Drupal (and more precisely to version 9), I've been reading resources and tutorials about custom theme creation for 3 days.
I can't figure out how to organize my templates and especially which templates I need to declare.

Let me explain, I have declared two new content types: Webinar and Expert Advice.
For each of these two elements, I want to define a template for :

- display the list of these entities
- display the details of an entity

#### 1)

This is where I have trouble understanding what I have to declare, I thought I was going to declare:
`page--webinar.html.twig` and `page--expert-advice.html.twig`: to display the list of each of these entities

but I realize that I don't know how to manage the display of the details of these entities in another page ? Should I declare a new template like `article--webinar.html.twig`? Or is it more of a `node--webinar.html.twig` concept?

#### 2)

How do I indicate which template to use for which type of content?

I discovered a hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function example_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $node->bundle();
  }
}
```

But I don't think this code automatically allows me to explicitly redirect to a list template or a content detail template

I apologize in advance if these questions may seem basic to you, but they pose a real problem of understanding and I currently do not understand with the resources I have studied for the moment

Thank you very much for your response

Comment: Try to enable [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) on your project: This will render the start/end of the used templates (and possible overwrites for the templates) as comments inside the source code. I think this will answer all your questions in an easy, visual way by just looking at the HTML source in the browser developer tools.

Comment: You probably should create node templates not page templates.

Comment: Thank you, I have already enabled local debugging to help me understand but I have a block on this working.
I come from Angular and I'm used to declaring my routing, everything is transparent, here I have trouble understanding what is done automatically by Drupal concerning the files (and their naming by extension)

Comment: For example, I have defined 4 links in my menu :
- Home : How do I redirect to a specific template page ? `page--home.html.twig` ? But in my back office I just indicated to redirect to "/home", i have no tools for selecting the file
- Webinars : Same struggle for the page dedicated to Webinars
- Expert advice : same as Webinars
- Contact : I want to redirect to a well-defined fixed page ? If I add a contact form, is it a block?

Comment: In a coupled world you have no access to routing as themer, you can't create pages/routes by creating template files. Instead you create pages in the CMS backend. Detail pages are usually created as content (nodes), listing pages are usually created using the views module. Those Pages then provide a list of possible template filenames.